# R equivalent to python's os.getpid() for parallel processing

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I frequently use parallel processing under both python (multiprocessing library) and r (snow, etc packages).
One thing I find extremely useful in python is the ability to log progress of individual instances using the unique identifier of the instance, so I can track, for instance, if the right number of instances are initiated and running properly.
To do that in python, I simply use os.getpid().

Is there a similar command in r? I have searched but have not found.

For instance, below is an example of an abstracted parallel code in r that I would like to have the instance log file include the instance ID in the log file name (line 17), along with time the process started:

```
rm(list = ls()) #remove all past worksheet variables
wd="D:/temp/" #location for log files
setwd(wd)
n_spp=30
spp_nmS=paste0("sp_",c(1:n_spp))
#sp_nm=spp_nmS[1]
library(snowfall)

#stop sinks
sink.reset <- function(){
  for(i in seq_len(sink.number())){
    sink(NULL)
  }
}

sp_parallel_run=function(sp_nm){
  file_nm=paste0(wd,sp_nm,"_log_",format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %H%M%S"), ".txt")
  con=file(file_nm, open="wt")
  sink(con)
  cat('\n', 'Started on ', date(), '\n') 
  ptm0 <- proc.time()

  #start code
  sp_nm
  Sys.sleep(10)

  #end code
  ptm1=proc.time() - ptm0
  jnk=as.numeric(ptm1[3])
  cat('\n','It took ', jnk, "seconds to model", sp_nm)

  sink.reset()
  close(con)
}

sfInit( parallel=TRUE, cpus=as.integer(Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'))) # 
sfExportAll()
sfLapply(x=spp_nmS, fun=sp_parallel_run)

sfRemoveAll()
sfStop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`??pid` returns `base::Sys.getpid` near the top of the list of results (will depend on what packages you have installed).

See `?Sys.getpid` for details.

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect! Feel dumb for not finding it, but it did not occur to me the obvious that r used the same pid terminology...